# Trouble with .xsd import in oracle

Tags: xml, database, oracle, report

I have trouble with schema import in oracle.

[scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vdta.jpg)

When i try import this, i have error:

> Error report -
>   ORA-31082: invalid attribute "totalDigits" specified in declaration of "(local simple type)"

totalDigits describe:

> May be used as facet for: xs:byte, xs:decimal, xs:int, xs:integer,
>   xs:long, xs:negativeInteger, xs:nonNegativeInteger,
>   xs:nonPositiveInteger, xs:positiveInteger, xs:short, xs:unsignedByte,
>   xs:unsignedInt, xs:unsignedLong, xs:unsignedShort

But, when i try this with another same syntax, there no error.

[For example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDWTr.jpg)